# Show progress bar in MapFragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a MapFragment to display some POIs on a map. I don't understand how can I show, and where i have to define, a progress bar to inform the user of the POI downloading process. I already have the code of a progress view, defined in XML as a LinearLayout containing a ProgressBar and a TextView.

Here is the FragmentMap code. I'm using both SherlockActionBar and Android Support v4.

```
public class MapFragment extends SherlockMapFragment {

private static final String TAG = MapFragment.class.getSimpleName(); 
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
         MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
     } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    View root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    // Showing status
    if(status==ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
         mMap = getMap();
    }
    else {
        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(), requestCode);
        dialog.show();
    }

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location myLocation= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    /*
    if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);  
            startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
    }
     */
    if(myLocation!=null)
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()), 15));

    new FetchAllPoiAsyncTask().execute();
    return root;
}

private class FetchAllPoiAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, PoiCategory[]> {
    @Override
    protected PoiCategory[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders= getApplicationContext().createAuthenticatedHttpHeader();

        List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        requestHeaders.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
        // Populate the headers in an HttpEntity object to use for the request
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
        // Create a new RestTemplate instance
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);
        // Perform the HTTP GET request
        try {
            ResponseEntity<PoiCategory[]> poiAll = restTemplate.exchange(getActivity().getString(R.string.poiAll_url), HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, PoiCategory[].class, "provider1234");
            return poiAll.getBody();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final PoiCategory[] poiCategories) {
        if(poiCategories==null)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occurred retrieving POIs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Retrieved "+poiCategories.length+" categories;");
        for(PoiCategory category : poiCategories) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Category "+category.getLabel()+" has "+category.getPoiList().length+" POIs;");
            Poi[] poiList = category.getPoiList();
            for(Poi poi : poiList) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(parsePoiPosition(poi))
                                    .title(poi.getTitle())
                                    .snippet(poi.getDescription()));
            }
        }
    }
}

private MainApplication getApplicationContext(){
    return (MainApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
}

public static LatLng parsePoiPosition(Poi poi) {
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(poi.getPositionLat());
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(poi.getPositionLong());
    LatLng result = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    return result;
}
}
```

I'm using this MapFragment in a DrawerLayout, adding it dynamically through fragment transactions. How can I add the progress view, setting it visible and invisible while the asyncTask downlaod the POIs? I have to add it to the FragmentMap or to the container DrawerLayout?

EDIT

I tried to modify the MapFragment this way:

1. Define a layout in progress_bar.xml (shown later)
2. Inflating it in the containerView through inflater.inflate()
3. Setting visible/invisible in onPreExecute()/onPostExecute()

But it doesn't works. ProgressBar is not shown, and POIs appears after some time in the map (I've added a Thread.sleep(5000) to simulate a long download)

Here is FragmentMap modified code. The showProgress() method is already tested and works well in another activity.

public class MapFragment extends SherlockMapFragment {

```
private static final String TAG = MapFragment.class.getSimpleName(); 
private GoogleMap mMap;
private View mDownloadProgressView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
         MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
     } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    View root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_bar, container);
    mDownloadProgressView= (View) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.download_progress);

    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    // Showing status
    if(status==ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
         mMap = getMap();
    }
    else {
        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(), requestCode);
        dialog.show();
    }

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location myLocation= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    /*
    if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);  
            startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
    }
     */
    if(myLocation!=null)
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()), 15));

    new FetchAllPoiAsyncTask().execute();
    return root;
}

private class FetchAllPoiAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, PoiCategory[]> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        showProgress(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected PoiCategory[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders= getApplicationContext().createAuthenticatedHttpHeader();

        List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        requestHeaders.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
        // Populate the headers in an HttpEntity object to use for the request
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Create a new RestTemplate instance
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);
        // Perform the HTTP GET request
        try {
            ResponseEntity<PoiCategory[]> poiAll = restTemplate.exchange(getActivity().getString(R.string.poiAll_url), HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, PoiCategory[].class, "provider1234");
            return poiAll.getBody();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final PoiCategory[] poiCategories) {
        showProgress(false);
        if(poiCategories==null)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occurred retrieving POIs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Retrieved "+poiCategories.length+" categories;");
        for(PoiCategory category : poiCategories) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Category "+category.getLabel()+" has "+category.getPoiList().length+" POIs;");
            Poi[] poiList = category.getPoiList();
            for(Poi poi : poiList) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(parsePoiPosition(poi))
                                    .title(poi.getTitle())
                                    .snippet(poi.getDescription()));
            }
        }
    }
}

private MainApplication getApplicationContext(){
    return (MainApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
}

public static LatLng parsePoiPosition(Poi poi) {
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(poi.getPositionLat());
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(poi.getPositionLong());
    LatLng result = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    return result;
}

/**
 * Shows the progress UI
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
        mDownloadProgressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mDownloadProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                .alpha(show ? 1 : 0)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mDownloadProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE
                                : View.GONE);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mDownloadProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

}

Here is progressBar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/download_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/download_poi_status_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="@string/downlaod_progress_message"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a ProgressBar in the xml file,  set the visible property  in invisible... Now in your onPreExecute method set the visibility in View. VISIBLE and in the postExecute make invisible again.

Comment: Good approach but I don't have XML. I have to define the progress bar in a separate XML file, and it's ok. But where I inflate it? Through inflater?

Comment: You can create the view in your code,  just: ProgressBar p = new ProgressBar(this) ;  now you can insert the view in your layout using the addView method

Comment: In the end I defined it as XML in the parent view, a drawerLayout, setting it visible/not_visible in pre/post execute. Doing so I can retrieve it in the Fragment through findViewById and I don't have to inflate/add_it_to_the_view programmatically. Drawback is that I have to modify the parent-view to act on a child, but in this way the progressBar can be re-used for other fragments in the same activity.

Answer (score 1):

Yould could just popup a dialog with the progress in there but if you do not want to block the user from using the map then another alternative would be to overlay another layout on top of the map fragment and put the progress bar in that layout

Comment: How I can overlay another layout? Trough inflater? container.addView()?

Comment: just create another linearlayout or whatever in your current activity xml with the same dimensions as the map